# jQuery + Multiple Checkboxes: Show div on checked, Hide on uncheck

Tags: jquery, animation, checkbox

I got multiple checkboxes generated from a PHP script.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="item[]" value="1" />

<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="item[]" value="2" />

<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="item[]" value="3" />

<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="item[]" value="4" />
```

Now, once a checkbox gets checked - I want to show a div with options like "Delete Selected". But, after all checkboxes are unchecked, the DIV should disappear again.
I have got the following code, but it does not hide the DIV.

```
    $(".checkbox").live('click', function () {

        countChecked () ;

        if (countChecked() == "1" ) {

            $("div#options").fadeOut("medium") ;

        } else {

            if ( $("div#options").is(":hidden") ) {

                $("div#options").fadeIn ( "medium" ) ;

            }

        }

    });
```

Also, the "countChecked"-function is shown below.

```
    function countChecked() {

        var n = $("input.checkbox:checked").length;

    }
```

Comment: For a start your function isn't returning anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function should return the value:

```
function countChecked() {
    return $("input.checkbox:checked").length;
}
```

And you want to check if the amount is **0**, also you can remove the duplicate call to `countChecked`

```
$(".checkbox").live('click', function () {
    if (countChecked() == 0 ) {
```

Comment: @Roel, if you just want to check if whether there are checked or not, you can simplify the function to just `return !!$("input.checkbox:checked").length;`. When length is 0, it will return false, true otherwise. :) so that your `if` statement would just be `if (countChecked()) { } else { }`

Answer (score 0):

in your `countChecked()`-function, use return statement..

```
 function countChecked() {

        var n = $("input.checkbox:checked").length;
        return n;

    }
```

and while clicking on checkboxes...

```
 $(".checkbox").live('click', function () {

        if (countChecked() == 0 ) {

            $("div#options").fadeOut("medium") ;

        } else {

            if ( $("div#options").is(":hidden") ) {

                $("div#options").fadeIn ( "medium" ) ;

            }

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$('.checkbox').live('click',function(){
    // if you just checked the current one, no need to check the rest
    if (this.checked)
    {
      $('#options').fadeIn('medium');
    }
    else // if you just unchecked
    {
        if ( !$('.checkbox:checked').length ) // check the whole group
        {
            $('#options').fadeOut('medium');
        }
    }
});
```

**demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/wZWbS/

Answer (score 0):

Working: http://jsfiddle.net/NkkJF/

Answer (score 0):

Another version, with tiny optimalization: http://jsfiddle.net/Briganti/XNWEP/

Have fun :)